# Funky rendering in IE for HTML + CSS

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, rendering

http://churchcentral.com/rfi.php?site_id=4&division_id=2144 is the page, and IE only is the problem.  If you notice, the text at the end of "Step 2", the text "the next page" is repeated.  If you highlight either of those portions of text, IE will highlight both of them.

Is this a bug in IE? We've seen this happen on the same page, but with different text, at different times, and it's causing issues with some people.

Any help would be great.

Comment: There are many bugs in IE, especially when you use a lot of floats, and double-especially when you work in Quirks Mode. I suggest cutting down on the floatery and adding a suitable <!DOCTYPE> so that IE switches to Standards Mode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is there a specific reason why that paragraph has `float: left` applied? If I remove this, it displays correctly.

Furthermore, you're copying exactly the same style as the `<h2>` above for step 1. You could simply use `<h2>` instead of `<p>` for step 2 as well, right? I mean, your outline is pretty weird as of now.

**ETA:** Nearly everything on that page floats, which leads me to a very big question mark:

As I see it, it's a very simple (layout-wise) top-to-bottom page. I think you can streamline many things in that CSS.

You can easily play around with disabling or changing certain CSS rules in IE's developer tools.

Answer (score 1):

If you remove the clear and float properties of that paragraph you'll see in firefox that the floating text field above it is probably the cause of it. Because all of those floats probably IE can't handle it anymore at a certain point, IE has never been the best at handling floats. I don't see what the floats are for either, so do you really need it?